# diff3 output in git conflict style, including mergeable hunks

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, diff3

I would like to produce a file consisting of the three-way diff of three files, with every difference represented as a conflict in the git style.  That is, common lines are shown verbatim, and differing sections of a file are shown with conflict markers "<<<<<<", "||||||", "======", and ">>>>>>" (also called "conflict brackets"):

```
common line 1
common line 2
<<<<<<<
text from mine.txt
|||||||
text from base.txt
more text from base.txt
=======
text from yours.txt
>>>>>>>
common line 3
common line 4
<<<<<<<
same text in mine.txt and yours.txt, none in base.txt
|||||||
=======
same text in mine.txt and yours.txt, none in base.txt
>>>>>>>
common line 5
common line 6
```

I would like **every difference** to be marked with conflict brackets, including differences that are mergeable.  And I would like to obtain the output **without human intervention**.

Here are some options that do not work:

- `git diff` only takes two files as input; that is, it compares two things rather than three.
- `git merge-file` does not show mergeable differences (it merges them).
- `diff3 -m` is like `git merge-file`: close: it shows the whole file, with conflict markers for
  conflicts, but it does not show conflict markers for mergeable differences.
- `diff3` shows all the differences, even mergeable ones, but not in the given format.
- `diff3 -A` does not show all the differences, and mergeable ones are not output with conflict markers.

I can write a program that takes the `diff3` output and the original files, and outputs the conflicted file in git style.  However, I would prefer to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Git's `vimdiff` mergetool shows you all four versions (ours, base, theirs, results-so-far), you can step through the changes, including all the automerged ones, with `]c` and `[c` and see everything, `1do` to take the local version, `2do` to take the base version, `3do` to take the remote version.

Comment: Yes, there are many tools that show all four versions interactively.  However, I want a file in exactly the above format, produced without human interaction.  I don't believe `vimdiff` can output such a file.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's just you, then.